# How do I overload new MyClass Classy=new MyClass[n] with my constructors?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am making test code to try to hack this out. I want to allocate/instantiating an array of my class. I want to initialize it as best I can, including allocating/instantiating my class MyClass(){_i++}. Right now i am doing two
operations,

```
MyClass[] ClassyChassis=new MyClass[4];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++) ClassyChassis[i]=new MyClass();
```

I can do stuff in MyClass constructor MyClass(). But I would like to give each array member knowledge of where it is in the array, assign default values, etc. etc.

Why can't I do this by overloading MyClass[] perhaps with

```
MyClass ClassyChassis=new MyClass[5]();

MyClass[5](initalizer0,initalizer1,initalier2);
```

Answer (score 1):

MyClass[] isn't a class in and of itself, it is an array of type MyClass. You can't add a constructor on the built-in array type.

A factory method would work. Create a factory class and add a method called CreateMyClassCollection(int number, param1, param2, param3)

```
public static class MyClassFactory
{
    public static List<MyClass> CreateMyClassCollection(int number, param1, param2, param3)
    {
        List<MyClass> items = new List<MyClass>();
        for (int counter=0;counter<number;counter++)
        {
            items.Add(new MyClass(param1,param2,param3);   
        }
        return items;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the class is defined to have two properties name and ID,

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int SomeID { get; set; }
    public string someName { get; set; }   
}
```

you can declare and initialize the class array as like the following:

```
  MyClass[] MyClassArray = { new MyClass(){SomeID=1,someName="aName"},
                             new MyClass(){SomeID=10,someName="bName"},
                             new MyClass(){SomeID=11,someName="cName"},
                             new MyClass(){SomeID=12,someName="dName"} 
                           };
```

or else you can use a List of `MyClass`

```
List<MyClass> MyClassList = new List<MyClass>(){ new MyClass(){SomeID=1,someName="aName"},
                                                 new MyClass(){SomeID=10,someName="bName"},
                                                 new MyClass(){SomeID=11,someName="cName"},
                                                 new MyClass(){SomeID=12,someName="dName"} 
                                                };
```